# How to print images in a table using loop

Tags: java, bluej

I need to print out a movie recommender that suggests similar movies and their details on an html. The IDE I have to use for the assignment is BlueJay. The below code is very basic but I would like to start table row and then have at least 3 images printed side-by-side in the row. As you can see, the table rows and headers are created within the for-loop, and I wanted to put a counter in ([first in for loop]i.e count = 0) and ([end of for-loop] count++);. Then I could ensure that only 3 images are printed per row `(if(count%3 == 0){ "</tr">"<tr">}";`

```
<ArrayList<Rating>> movies    
for(Rating R : movies){
    System.out.println(<"tr">);
    System.out.println(<"th>");
    System.out.println(<"img src=r.getMoviePoster()>"<"/th">);
    System.out.println(<"td>"movietitle and year"<"/td>");
}
System.out.println("}");
```

Comment: Which language are you looking for here? Code looks like java, tags suggest javascript.